# How to display in view data get item Id after displaying many pictures from foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have my class named PropertyDetailsModel that displays in View named "propertyForAll" all the data per Id.
I want if the user select one Id in View named "propertyForAll", it should be able to open a new page and only display on the new page, property for the selected Id.

So how would I pass data from view (where all the data is displayed ) to new page view. (when the user select one Id)

There's no **db. ...FindById** to use in the controller for the new page...  as I see in many tutos... it's a different architecture made by solution architectures who left the company.

Can I loop through PropertyDetailsModel and pass it to the **returnView()**

```
    public class PropertyDetailsModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string SubTitle { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        ...

    }


Code for new page controller
[HttpGet]
    public ViewResult displayItemSelected(int? id)
    {

        if (id == null)
        {

            return HttpNotFoundResult();

        }

        PropertyDetailsModel propertyModel;

        propertyModel.Id
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the model directly to `View`:

```cs
var propertyModel = new PropertyDetailsModel();
return View(propertyModel);
```

Then, in the RazorPage (I believe `Model` is of type `object` and therefore needs to be promoted/cast to the expected type):

```
<p>Property Name: @{((PropertyDetailsModel)Model).Name}</p>
```

Alternatively, you can pass arbitrary data to a View Page like so:

Both `ViewData` and `ViewBag` are accessible from within a Razor/View Page (.cshtml). ViewData is a `Dictionary<string, object>`, ViewBag is a `dynamic`.

If you just put the model in the ViewBag:

```cs
var propertyModel = new PropertyDetailsModel();
ViewBag.PropertyModel = propertyModel;
return View();
```

The RazorPage will be able to access `ViewBag` and by extension `ViewBag.PropertyModel` like so:

```
<p>Property Name: @{ViewBag.PropertyModel.Name}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems like I need to fetch it by Id like so (**var propertyModel = new PropertyDetailsModel(m => m.Id == id);**). I'm going to test your above solution soon and let you know.